# Expect: How to handle spawn id exp4 not open error

Tags: expect

My expect script:

```
foreach host $hostlist {
  puts $host
  set timeout 3
  spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
  expect {
    -re "closed by remote host" { exp_continue }
    -re "RSA key fingerprint" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue }
    -re "(P|p)assword: " { send "$pass\r"; exp_continue }
    -re $prompt { send "$cmd\r" }
    eof
  }
...
```

is throwing this error and exits right away.

```
spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no myuserid@example.net
**expect: spawn id exp4 not open**
    while executing
"expect -re $prompt"
    ("foreach" body line 12)
    invoked from within
"foreach host $hostlist {
  puts $host
  set timeout 3
  spawn ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"
  expect {
    -re "closed by rem..."
    (file "./a" line 36)
```

whenever the ssh login attempt encounters some problem on a host like:

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I tried to put various "expect" regexps but couldn't make it continue to the next host but it abruptly exits.

Anyone know of a trick on how to make it not exit but move onto the next host?

If it's not possible using tcl/expect, would it be possible using the expect module with Python or Perl?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Re "*would it be possible using the expect module with Python or Perl?*", Yes.

Comment: Hi ikegami - Any sample Python/Perl pexpect/pxssh code to  share for handling this error?

Comment: If you have problems with your Perl or Python code, feel free to post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    -re "closed by remote host" { exp_continue }
```

to

```
    -re "closed by remote host" { continue }
```

You want to go to the next `foreach` iteration, not loop within this `expect` command to look for the next pattern.

Comment: Hi glenn - Outstanding! That does it. I searched quite a bit but nowhere I could find a solution to this issue. Your answer clearly solves the problem and I couldn't find it anywhere else. Thank you so much!!!